# Entity Framework 6 Code First From Database context performs CREATE TABLE on existing an VIEW

Tags: database, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a production Oracle database server maintained by our ERP partner.

For some custom development I need to connect to this Oracle database using Entity Framework 6. I have a user that can SELECT any table on the ERP schema and I create views in the schema/user used in my EF context.

The view itself is pretty straightforward, a few joins but all referencing tables on another schema ofcourse.

i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE ERP.M_GROUP 
(
  FILE VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) 
, MATFAM VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, GROUP VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, OMS1 VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) 
, OMS2 VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) 
, RESTW_FACTOR1_I NUMBER 
) 


CREATE VIEW EF6CTX.GROUPS AS
SELECT
    GROUP Id,
    MAX(OMS1) Name
FROM 
    M_GROUP
WHERE 
    FILE = 'BAT'
    AND MATFAM IN ('B','C','I', 'K')
GROUP BY GROEP
```

When I connect to my database using Visual Studio's Entity Framework 6 Code First from Database identifing as user EF6CTX I can select this view and my model is created as it should.

But when I try to read these groups..

```
var ctx = new TestContext();
ctx.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
foreach (var group in ctx.GROUPS)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group: {0}", group.NAME);
}
```

I get this result:

```
Opened connection at 21/11/2014 15:29:05 +01:00

Started transaction at 21/11/2014 15:29:05 +01:00

create table "EF6CTX"."GROUPS"
(
    "ID" varchar2(20 CHAR) not null,
    "NAME" varchar2(60 CHAR) null,
    constraint "PK_GROUPS" primary key ("ID")
)


-- Executing at 21/11/2014 15:29:05 +01:00

-- Failed in 217 ms with error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

The user EF6CTX has no permissions to create a table.. ofcourse. But why is it trying to create a table? It should USE the existing view!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed when migrations are disabled:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(null);
```